# PCA, properties of norm and or orthonormality of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, orthonormal

I'm reading a paper on a particular form of PCA and I'm struggling to understand one part.

We have $||\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{XGH}^T||^2$
with $\mathbf{X}$ a $n\times p$ (data) matrix, $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ some $p\times k$ matrices, and $\mathbf{H}$ is orthonormal.
They then proceed to say that since $\mathbf{H}$ is orthonormal, let $\mathbf{H}_\bot$ be any orthogonal matrix such that $[\mathbf{H};\mathbf{H}_\bot]$ is $p\times p$ orthogonal.

Then $||\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{XGH}^T||^2=||\mathbf{XH}_\bot||^2+||\mathbf{XH}-\mathbf{XG}||^2$

So not having a really strong linear algebra background, I really don't understand what are the step allowing us to do that, my initial intuition was that we use the fact that $\mathbf{H}^T\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{I}_{k\times k}$ but I can't find the same result as them and don't understand what is the goal of constructing this $p\times p$ orthonormal matrix. My second thought was that maybe it's related to some properties of the norm that I'm not aware of.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks !

Comment: Within standard terminology, one does not refer to a matrix as "orthonormal". A matrix can have *orthonormal columns*, which is what you seem to mean by the statement that $H$ is "orthonormal". A square matrix with orthornormal columns is called an *orthogonal* matrix.

Comment: Do **not** delete your question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person (or persons) who took the time to answer your question, and is disrespectful to future readers, who might find your question and its answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Because $[H \ \ H_\perp]$ is orthogonal (i.e. square with orthonormal columns), we have $\|M[H \ \ H_\perp]\| = \|M\|$ for any matrix $M$. Moreover, we must have $H^\top H_\perp = 0$. On the other hand, we have
$$
(X - XGH^\top)\pmatrix{H & H_\perp} = \pmatrix{(X - XGH^\top)H & (X - XGH^\top)H_\perp}
\\ = 
\pmatrix{XH- XGH^\top H & XH_{\perp} - GXH^\top H_\perp}
\\ = \pmatrix{XH - XG & XH_\perp}.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\|X - XGH^\top\|^2 = \|\pmatrix{XH - XG & XH_\perp}\|^2 = \|XH - XG\|^2 + \|XH_\perp\|^2.
$$

Comment: Got it ! Thanks a lot for the very quick answer.